# Difference between the content of a struct pointer and of a int pointer (or other variable types) (c/c++)?

Tags: c++, c

As the question says. Is there some difference between the content of them?

Why do we have to declare the variable type before the pointer ????

Does the c process them differently?

Exemple:

```
typedef struct{
    int a;
    char b;
} some_st;

int main(){
    some_st *p;
    int *q;
}
```

Just a note: I came up with this question after work with linked lists.

Thank you for reading and answering.

Comment: Oh, thank you @Kninnug, haven't seen that one.

Answer (score 1):

the pointers are the same size, but one points to an `int` and the other one to a `struct`. The reason to declare them accordingly is that the compiler can tell you when you use them incorrectly.

if you think you're above that, you can use `void*` for all your pointers, or use a language with even less type checking.

Comment: Wrong. Pointers may not be of the same size. Neither pointer points to an object, they are uinitialized.

Comment: theoretically, yes. In practice, they are the same size.

Comment: Nope, an implementation may define different pointer sizes and representation in practice, i.e. on a real machine.

Comment: @2501: Can you name an implementation where that is the case?

Answer (score 0):

C doesn't define how pointers are represented.

Pointers of different types may have different sizes, different alignments requirements and different bit representaion.

For example this is a completely valid result of an implementation:

```
sizeof( int* ) != sizeof( long* )
```

as is :

```
sizeof( int* ) != sizeof( some_st* )
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in the size or "structure" of the pointer itself, however the declaration does affect two things:

1. It tells the compiler how to handle the value being pointed to (int or struct or whatever) - that is, what to assume the pointed type is.
2. The way pointer arithmetic is being performed. That is what memory location ptr++ or ptr[4] evaluates to. For example, Assuming the struct has, say 12 bytes size, ptr++ will result in the address being incremented by at least 12.